# How do I make a plot with 3 scatterplots?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to make one plot with 3 scatterplots, but I have no idea how. I can plot them seperately as:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

kat %>%
    filter(Sex %in% c("F")) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = Bwt, y = Hwt)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap("Sex")
```

[image]

```
kat %>%
    filter(Sex %in% c("M")) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = Bwt, y = Hwt)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap("Sex")
```

[image]

```
kat %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = Bwt, y = Hwt)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap("Sex")
```

[image]

I have searched in previous Stack Overflow topics, but without any luck.

Comment: You say "histograms" but make "scatterplots", which is it?

Comment: Ups, it was a typo, meant scatterplots! But either one of them will do the job.

Comment: What do you mean with 3 scatterplots? The cats data consist of 2 variables (Bwt and Hwt) and one factor (F and M).  If you look to `Hwt` as a function of `Bwt` you get 2 scatterplots - one for F and one for M as you have shown above.

Comment: Hi @MarBlo, i want to combine all the three above plots in one plot. That's the idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is what I understand what you want. Starting from your three plots and then putting them together here with `patchwork`.

```r
library(MASS)
data(cats)

library(dplyr)

library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

p1 <- cats %>%
  filter(Sex %in% c("F")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Bwt, y = Hwt)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap("Sex")

p2 <- cats %>%
  filter(Sex %in% c("M")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Bwt, y = Hwt)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap("Sex")

p3 <- cats %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Bwt, y = Hwt)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap("Sex")


(p1 | p2)/
  p3
```

[image]

Comment: This is excatly what i was thinking, thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

Since you want two facet to be "individual Sex" and one to be "all", then we can duplicate the data:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
mtcars %>%
  mutate(cyl = "All") %>%
  bind_rows(mutate(mtcars, cyl = as.character(cyl))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(mpg, disp)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~ cyl)
```

[image: wrapped facets with "all"]

This premise works regardless of your plotting preference (e.g., scatterplot or histogram).

The intermediate `mutate(mtcars, cyl=as.character(cyl))` is because the duplicated data has a string for `cyl` whereas the original data is `integer`; since your `"Sex"` column is already `character`, you likely won't need that intermediate `as.character`. If they are `factor`s, however, you may need to proactively manage the levels of the factor to include `"All"` (or whatever string you prefer).

Comment: Thank you for the reply, r2evans. 

I can't make it work.. hmm.. i'm having trouble understanding how to put "individual sex" and "both sex" in that code.

I reckon you want me to some how put it in bind_rows( ), right?

Comment: I'd expect that `kat %>% mutate(Sex = "Both sexes") %>% bind_rows(kat) %>% ggplot(...) + ...` should work. What errors are you getting?

Comment: Well, i'm not getting any errors.

The code im running is:

```kat %>%
    mutate(Sex = "male", "female", "both")
  bind_rows(mutate(kat)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Bwt, Hwt)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~ Sex)```

where 
```male <- kat %>%
    filter(Sex %in% c("F")) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = Bwt, y = Hwt)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap("Sex")```and


```female <- kat %>%
    filter(Sex %in% c("M")) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = Bwt, y = Hwt)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap("Sex")```
and

```both <-kat %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = Bwt, y = Hwt)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap("Sex")```

Comment: The problem is it still only returns a plot with 2 scatterplots. One for male and one for female.

Comment: Oh god.. i forgot a %>%...

Comment: I have no idea what you are intending to do with `mutate(Sex = "male", "female", "both")`, it makes no sense, and as I mentioned before, you don't need the `as.character` mutate phrase, so your `mutate(kat)` is doing nothing. Literally, try `kat %>% mutate(Sex = "both") %>% bind_rows(kat) %>% ggplot(aes(Bwt, Hwt)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~ Sex)`.